# Adding active class in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have two iterations, one list and its wrapper. I want to add a class when I click on the item. But now the class added all wrapper list item. Please see the below link.

```
$scope.select= function(index) {
   $scope.selected = index; 
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9me2L1ev/

Please anyone help me. 
Thanks
Vimal

Answer (score 2):

You need to do something like this you have logical error.

```
<div ng-app='app' class="filters_ct" ng-controller="selectFilter">
    <div ng-repeat="filter1 in filters">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="filter in filters" ng-click="filter1[selected] = $index " ng-class="{active: $index == filter1[selected]}">
            <span class="filters_ct_status"></span>
            {{filter.time}}
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div></div>
```

check out updated fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/9me2L1ev/1/)

Comment: Thanks ngLover.. :)
A small issue, when I click on the item in other group not removing the active class.

Comment: so you want all the active classes under all ul li should be removed

Answer (score 2):

You need to combo two `$index` value. Reference to `parent $index` using `$parent.$index`

```
ng-click="select($parent.$index, $index)" ng-class="{active: $parent.$index + '.' + $index == selected}"
```

and

```
$scope.select= function(parentIndex, index) {
       $scope.selected = parentIndex + '.' + index; 
};
```

Check this https://jsfiddle.net/56dc8dej/

Answer (score 0):

[I have updated code in his link](https://jsfiddle.net/9me2L1ev/3/)

```
<div ng-app='app' class="filters_ct" ng-controller="selectFilter">
<div>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="filter in filters" ng-click="select($index)" ng-class="{active: $index == selected}">
        <span class="filters_ct_status"></span>
        {{filter.time}}
    </li>
</ul>
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to consider the parent index...

```
<div ng-app='app' class="filters_ct" ng-controller="selectFilter">
    <div ng-repeat="filter1 in filters">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="filter in filters" ng-click="select($parent.$index, $index)" ng-class="{active: $parent.$index+','+$index == selected }">
                <span class="filters_ct_status"></span>
                {{filter.time}}
            </li>
       </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in you controller:

```
...
$scope.select= function(pindex, index) {
    $scope.selected = pindex+','+index; 
};
...
```